# Export SSL certificate uploaded in Elastic Loadbalancer(ELB)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, aws-sdk, amazon-elb

Is there any way to export/download the uploaded SSL certificate and private keys from ELB ?

Any solution via SDK or console will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

The documentation does not appear to explicitly explain this, but there's an intuitive and compelling argument to be made that this design limitation is correct -- that anyone authorized to be in possession of the private key already has a way to obtain it.

If the service allowed it to be retrieved, that would present a substantial security risk.

If all you need is to inspect the certificate or chain, that's easy enough using any web browser, or from the command line with `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect hostname:port` to an endpoint using the certificate,  so I'm assuming that what you really want here is the private key... which can't be retrieved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand it now.
I knew that would security flaw, but wanted to know if it's possible or not.